# Output error in comparing characters from two strings

Tags: java, string, debugging, character

I'm stuck with my a piece of code I'm creating. My IDE is Eclipse and when I use its debugging feature, to trace what's happening on each line, it outputs perfectly. However, when I click the "run" project, it just outputs a blank screen:

```
public static void compareInterests(Client[] clientDetails)
{
    int interests = 0;

    for (int p = 0; p < numberOfClients; p++)
    {
        for (int q = 0; q < numberOfClients; q++)
        {
            String a = clientDetails[p].getClientInterests();
            String b = clientDetails[q].getClientInterests();

            int count = 0;
            while (count < a.length())
            {
                if (a.charAt(count) == b.charAt(count))
                    interests++;
                count++;
            }

            if ((interests >= 3) && (clientDetails[p].getClientName() != clientDetails[q].getClientName()))
                System.out.print (clientDetails[p].getClientName() + " is compatible with " + clientDetails[q].getClientName());
            interests = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The code is designed to import an object array which contains information on a client's name and a client's interests. The client's interests are stored in the format "01010", where each 1 means they are interested in that activity, each 0 means they are not.

My code compares each character of every client's string with every other client's string and outputs the results for all client's that don't have the same name and have three or more interests in common.

When I run this code through Java's debugger, it outputs fine - but when I click run project or compile, I just get a blank screen.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I changed the section

```
clientDetails[p].getClientName() != clientDetails[q].getClientName()
```

to

```
clientDetails[p].getClientName().equals(clientDetails[q].getClientName()
```

as the people in the answers below suggested. However, I'm still getting blank output. Any other ideas (and also, why did Eclipse's debugger ignore this and output everything correctly?)

Sample input looks like this:

```
 Sophia Candappa     F 23 00011
 Jade Clarke         F 25 00011
```

Ignore the gender and age (F and 23/25) as I've taken care of them in other sections.

Edit 2:

Okay, even stranger now! If I add this code after interest = 0, like so:

```
    interests = 0;
    System.out.println("");
```

I get output from it (horribly formatted output, as I may get a result, new line, result, then four new lines, then result, depending on who matches up with who in the loop statements.
I really don't get why that line gives output. Anyone??

Comment: I suppose 'blank screen' means that you do not see any output on the console. Did you try to add more debug statements (System.out...)?

Comment: @home: Yeah, no output - sorry, should have been more specific. I did line breaks in the debugging section, but I don't know any debug statements - still learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the relevant snippet from the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) that you're missing:

> Optionally, a PrintStream can be created so as to flush automatically;
>   this means that the flush method is automatically invoked after a byte
>   array is written, one of the println methods is invoked, or a newline
>   character or byte ('\n') is written

The only output in your function is System.out.print() calls.  Therefore, nothing ever forces a flush of System.out's buffer, and there's no guarantee that you'll see that output.  The debugger (can) be a bit more aggressive about flushing the output buffer, which is why you see your output from within the debugger.  And the above-quoted text explains why adding the empty println() call fixed your problem - println() forces the buffer to be written out.

Comment: As I'm completely new to the idea of flushing a buffer, a few questions. What does flushing a buffer mean? And why did it need to be done in that snippet of code, but nowhere else in my program (or any other programming I've done to date).

Comment: A buffer is a holding area used for performance reasons, usually to combine multiple small actions into a single bigger one.  In this case - writing to a file (or the screen) is typically an expensive action, but doesn't get much more expensive as the amount you write goes up.  So when you call System.out.print(), it takes the text you add and places it into this holding area.  This won't actually get sent to the real destination (the output window) until the buffer gets filled up.  'flush'ing the buffer forces it to do so immediately.

Comment: As for why you're just now seeing this for the first time...mostly luck.  Most programs write more than one line, so you'll usually end up writing a newline or calling println(); both of those force the output to the screen.  And the JVM (or other framework) has leeway about when to flush buffers on its own - which is why the debugger can show you the output, but when running normally you don't see it; the VM is behaving differently when you're in debug mode.

Comment: So was it the fact that unless the "if" statement is satisfied, there was no printing being done during the for statements?
Thanks for your answers by the way!

Comment: No - I think the difference is just that you called System.out.print() in your original code, instead of System.out.println(). If you changed the call where you're printing a match out to be System.out.println() and deleted the extra call you added below interests = 0, you'd get reliable output with a single match per line and no extra blank lines.  It is also true, of course, that if your if condition is never met you'll never get any output at all.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I didn't want a println either below interest = 0 or above it where you suggested, so I placed it after the first for statement and before the second for statement. This solved the problem and output everything as desired. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.equals` instead of the `==` operator for comparing `String` content:

```
if ((interests >= 3) && (!clientDetails[p].getClientName().equals(clientDetails[q].getClientName()))
```

Comment: Two questions. Firstly, why did Eclipse debugging not flag that up? It output everything correctly. Secondly and more importantly, even after changing that, I get blank output. Any more ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Java ain't javascript...

Unlike javascript, in java the `==` operator tests if the two objects are the same exact instance - ie if the two variables refer to the object.

When comparing the *value* of objects, use the `.equals()` method.
Note that the default implementation for `.equals()` (in the `Object` class) is in fact the same as an `==` comparison, but classes that override it (like `String`) compare their state (value).

This is one of the most common mistakes made by programmers new to java.

What you want is:

```
!clientDetails[p].getClientName().equals(clientDetails[q].getClientName())
```

or perhaps

```
!clientDetails[p].getClientName().equalsIgnoreCase(clientDetails[q].getClientName())
```

Comment: Two questions. Firstly, why did Eclipse debugging not flag that up? It output everything correctly. Secondly and more importantly, even after changing that, I get blank output. Any more ideas why?

Comment: @AndrewMartin Eclipse didn't flag it because it's not an java syntax error, it's a bug in *your* code - it's valid java, just not the java you want. See edited answer for what you should code